# Does physicalism imply everything can be defined?

Tags: terminology, knowledge, definitions, physicalism

Does physicalism imply everything can be defined at least to a certain extent?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined"?

Comment: The "everything can be defined" seems to be to be contradicted by the "to a certain extent".

Comment: I don't think physicalism "infer" that everything can be defined, but rather *suggests* that everything in our human capability to comprehend *can* be defined, if we'd have the right amount of time and resources. But I'm not sure if that's something intrinsic to physicalism, but rather the common view in science overall.

Comment: We cannot define absolutely **all**, neither in math nor is physics nor in philosophy.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: That means, in mathematics set theorists order things that they cannot define and cannot distinguish. Father, forgive them, for they know not what they do.

Comment: Yes, it implies. But without definition even the person wouldn't exists, because the thought implies defining things..

Comment: In a very literal sense, everything is defined in physicalism to be "the sum total of all matter in the universe."  That definition, when paired with "... at least to a certain extent" seems sufficient to "define" all meaningful subsets of Everything.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: I think here the question concerns definitions of individuals, and in particular of ideas that, contrary to material objects, do not exist without existing in at least one mind.

Comment: @Wilhelm Oh, of course. But the "at least to a certain extent" gives great leeway in approaching the problem, and I think there's a lot of interesting philosophy to be had in the process of trying to rephrase that problematic construction.

Answer (score 2):

Two senses of definition are 'real' and 'nominal'.

'Real' definition describes the essential, fundamental feature(s) of a thing. If everything is physical, then a 'real' definition could (in principle) be given of every individual (state, object or event), every class and every attribute. This is clearly so since the essential, fundamental feature of every individual (state, object or event), every class and every attribute would be that it is physical.

One snag is that if everything is physical, then a 'real' definition would have itself to be physical. I have difficulties conceiving what a physical definition of a physical individual, class or attribute would be.

Perhaps you could get round the problem by refining 'everything' : you could have 1st-order things such as physical individuals, classes and attributes, and 2nd-order things such as concepts and signs in terms of which 1st-order things can be defined. But some analytic work needs to be done on 'everything'.

'Nominal' definition is the analysis of one concept or sign in terms of another concept or sign. (Pluralise if need be as above : 'concepts or signs'.) Thus 'A prime number is a positive integer that is divisible only by itself and 1.' If - IF - everything can be nominally defined under physicalism, it can be nominally defined under any other theory too - spiritualism, panpsychism, animism and so on and on. Why not ? This gives no punch to the claim that under physicalism everything can be defined, since in this respect physicalism is no different from any other theory.

Comment: Unless you define unthought thoughts as thoughts and undefined definitions as definitions, a definition must have a real-world representation by neurons or other states of matter. Hence the set of definitions is finite.

Comment: @Wilhelm. Scienti cedo : GT

Answer (score 0):

Physicalism is restricted to a finite number of particles (at least in the accessible universe) and hence to a finite number of definitions. If there are infinitely many ideas, for instance numbers, then most of them cannot be defined.

If we consider what the mathematicians of the 19th century could not yet know, and what those of the 20th century seem to have pushed out of their minds, we recognize: The universe contains less than 10^80 protons and certainly less than 10^100 particles which can store bits. Therefore, an upper limit of the number of definitions is 10^100. The supremum is certainly less.

Comment: This seems weakly justified (why must there be a finite number of particles? why are particles the only quantity you measure? why can you not have physicalism with infinite universes? the naturals are well-defined and not finite) and it's not clear how it relates to the question.

Comment: The universe may be infinite, but the radius of the accessible sphere the contents of which can be utilized for writing, thinking, storing definitions is restricted by the ct where c is light velocity and t is time. This is a finite domain and will forever remain so.

Comment: The sequence or set of natural numbers is well-defined as well as the *typical* natural number, for instance its unique prime decomposition. But that does not define any individual number (except 1).

Comment: That doesn't follow if t is unbounded; at any point in time the universe would have finite size, but there may be no finite size which is an upper bound for the universe as t increases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "typical natural number"; I cannot just take an average.

Comment: There is probably no finite bound. But even an ever expanding eternal universe is finite at every instance and hence allows only for a finite number of definitions.

Comment: A typical natural number has typical properties: It has a unique prime decomposition, it is not negative, it can be represented in decimal system without radix point etc.

Comment: But if you have a universe whose state evolution is affected by values input into it at a later time, those values must be part of what a physicalist considers.

Comment: I would not call those properties of a typical natural number, but typical properties of a natural number.

Comment: Whatever a physicalist considers, he has less tha 10^100 neurons. Therefore he cannot consider more. That was the question.

Comment: If the question is about what *humans* could do, then sure, though this doesn't limit the number of particles considered if their state is compressible; quines exist. If it was more abstract, talking about a more theoretical "is there a definition", I would disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "physicalism" as far as its metaphysical denotations/connotations go, but as far as physics goes the answer is "no", i.e., not everything can be defined.

That's erroneously contradicted by https://books.google.com/books?id=pQXSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA54 where Peres states his "G* Strong superposition principle. Any orthogonal basis represents a **realizable** maximal test." It's **realizable** that's the key word here.

There are an uncountably infinite number of possible orthogonal bases (an elementary fact from functional analysis), but only a countably infinite number of constructible test apparatus (there are several references about that, but I'm not offhand finding them). And that boils down to the existence of states that can neither be prepared nor tested for (contrary to Peres). And, like I parenthetically mentioned, I know I've read several such references, and will edit this to cite them if I come across them.

I'd typically leave it at that, but since this is philosophy rather than physics, I like to more (much more) broadly (and entertainingly) think of the above idea along the lines (perhaps in the spirit) suggested by Jean Giraudoux in The Madwoman of Chaillot (the first sentence is what's directly relevant, the rest icing on the cake),

```
COUNTESS. [...] are you so stupid as to think that just because
we're alone here, there's nobody else in the room? Do you consider
us so boring or so respulsive that of all the millions of beings,
imaginary or otherwise, who are prowling about in space looking
for a little company, there's not one who might possibly enjoy
spending a moment with us? On the contrary, my dear -- my house
is full of guests, always. They know that here, at least is one
place in the universe where they can come when they're lonely
and be sure of a welcome and a pleasant hour. And for my part,
I'm delighted to have them.
```